# Not saving geopoint for user using Parse

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I am trying to save the user's location but the code below is returning an error. Instead of creating a new key "currentLocation" it's returning an error and creating a key "hello." Why would that be?

```
[PFGeoPoint geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:^(PFGeoPoint *geoPoint, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"User is currently at %f, %f", geoPoint.latitude, geoPoint.longitude);
                [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:geoPoint forKey:@"currentLocation"];
                [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
            }
            else {
                [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:hello forKey:@"hello"];
            }
        }];
```

Comment: Have you properly asked for access to Location services for your app?

Comment: Could you please log the error in your `else { NSLog(@"%@", error); ...}`.

Comment: @TimothyWalters I just have to include it in the plist, right? If so, I did do that.

Comment: @YuchenZhong The error is: The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! I had to go to Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Options and add a Default Location.